# Remove listener with one parameter in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list of toggles which have parameters. I want to add and then remove listeners in runtime, but i want to keep those added via Unity Inspector. But the issue is that i can't remove listener with parameter int. I could use removeAll but removes all other listeners which i have on this toggles, which i don't want to. I just want this specific one

```
private void AddToggleEvents()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < onOffInfoPointsGroups.Count; i++)
    {
        int index = i;
        onOffInfoPointsGroups[index].onValueChanged.AddListener(func => OnOffInfoPointsGroup(index));
    }
}
private void RemoveToggleEvents()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < onOffInfoPointsGroups.Count; i++)
    {
        int index = i;
        onOffInfoPointsGroups[index].onValueChanged.RemoveListener(func => OnOffInfoPointsGroup(index));
    }
}
public void OnOffInfoPointsGroup(int index)
{
    toggleGroups[index].SetActive(onOffInfoPointsGroups[index].isOn);
    CommandPanel.instance.NeedToSave(true);
}
```

Comment: That's strange to me.  I usually assign the listener to a variable and then when I remove the listener I just pass the variable.  Very roughly:  `foo = func => OnOffInfoPointsGroup(index); ....AddListener(foo)` then `....RemoveListener(foo)`  Just gotta store the `foo`s somewhere, like a list of listeners.  Not sure what other people do to solve this.

Comment: won't work. I need to pass integer value.

Comment: When exactly are you hoping `OnOffInfoPointsGroup(1)` will execute?  Because it won't...ever.  When you call RemoveListener you should pass a UnityAction that you previously added with AddListener.  You are not doing that.  You're asking it to remove some new lambda function that has never been added to anything as a listener.  This will quietly do nothing.

Comment: One technique is for `AddToggleEvents()` to return an Action that, when called, will unsubscribe all of the listeners that `AddToggleEvents` installed.  Then just stash that Action somewhere and call that Action instead of `RemoveToggleEvents` when you want to remove all the listeners that `AddToggleEvents()` originally added.

Comment: Can u write an example? I tried with UnityAction<bool> because it accepts only that value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of general usefulness that demonstrates a few key concepts:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

[System.Serializable]
public class MyIntEvent : UnityEvent<int>
{
}

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    MyIntEvent m_MyEvent = new MyIntEvent();
    UnityAction unsubscribe;

    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Starting.  Press Any Key to increment counter.  Press A to subscribe.  Press Z to unsubscribe.  Press Q to quit.");
        // Add a default handler that won't be removed
        m_MyEvent.AddListener((x) => { Debug.Log("The counter was incremented."); }); 
    }

    UnityAction Subscribe(UnityAction<int> fn)
    {
        // Add the listener
        m_MyEvent.AddListener(fn);
        // Return a parameterless action that, when called, will remove the listener.
        return () => m_MyEvent.RemoveListener(fn);
    }

    static int counter = 0;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("q") && m_MyEvent != null) {
            Debug.Log("Quitting");
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
#endif
            Application.Quit();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("a") && m_MyEvent != null) {
            if (unsubscribe == null) {
                Debug.Log("Subscribing");
                unsubscribe = Subscribe((x) => { Debug.Log(string.Format("Current Counter Value: {0}.", x)); });
            }
            else {
                Debug.LogWarning("Already Subscribed");
            }
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown("z") && m_MyEvent != null) {
            if (unsubscribe != null) {
                Debug.Log("Unsubscribing");
                unsubscribe();
                unsubscribe = null;
            }
            else {
                Debug.LogWarning("Not Subscribed");
            }
        } else if (Input.anyKeyDown && m_MyEvent != null) {
            // Invoke the active listeners and pass them the current counter value
            m_MyEvent.Invoke(++counter);
        }
    }
}
```

### About the example

#### You can assign a Lambda to a UnityAction

```
UnityAction<int> fn = (x) => { Debug.Log(string.Format("Current Counter Value: {0}.", x)); };
```

This demonstrates the mechanics of assigning a lambda to a `UnityAction<int>`  This is a stand-in for your `onOffInfoPointsGroups[index].onValueChanged`.  (I think your value is a `bool` in your example, can't be sure.  I'm using an int counter for this generic example.)

In the actual example we pass it as a parameter to a `Subscribe` function in a similar way.

```
Subscribe((x) => { Debug.Log(string.Format("Current Counter Value: {0}.", x)); });
```

#### Remove exactly what you Added

```
m_MyEvent.AddListener(fn);
m_MyEvent.RemoveListener(fn);
```

When you call RemoveListener, you must pass in the same thing that you passed in for AddListener.  That's why we stash it in a variable: `fn`.

The following is an **anti-pattern** because you are removing something different from what you added.  This will not work.  The remove will silently remove nothing, leaving what was added still there--still listening.

```
m_MyEvent.AddListener((x) => { Debug.Log("OK"); });
m_MyEvent.RemoveListener((x) => { Debug.Log("Not OK"); });  // Wrong.  Don't do this.
```

With minimal extra syntax you could adopt this pattern:

```
UnityAction<int> fn;
m_MyEvent.AddListener(fn = (x) => { Debug.Log("OK"); });
m_MyEvent.RemoveListener(fn);
```

But you still have to remember that it was `m_MyEvent` that you subscribed to.  I actually like to go a step further and employ an *unsubscriber* pattern.

#### A pattern for subscriptions is to return a *remover*

This is a little extra, but I find it convenient.  Employ a pattern wherein upon adding a listener, the subscribing function returns a parameterless action that, when called, will remove the listener.  This is convenient because you don't need to retain the details about which event you subscribed to and what the listening function was.  You can just call the unsubscriber function that was returned from the subscriber.

As a pattern, it might look like this:

```
    UnityAction Subscribe(UnityAction<int> fn)
    {
        // Add the listener
        m_MyEvent.AddListener(fn);
        // Return an action that, when called, will remove the listener.
        return () => m_MyEvent.RemoveListener(fn);
    }
```

And when you call it, could would do:

```
   UnityAction unsubscribe = Subscribe(() => Debug.Log("OK"));
```

And to remove the listener:

```
   unsubscribe();
```

This example has the event baked into the Subscribe function, but it's not too hard to pass the event in separately too, to make something that is more generally useful.

The pattern is also not too bad to use in-line without any supporting infrastructure.

### Your example

I might fix your example like this:  I will unroll the *subscriber* pattern in-line now that you know what it is.

```
private UnityAction AddToggleEvents()
{
    List<UnityAction> removers = new List<UnityAction>();

    for (int i = 0; i < onOffInfoPointsGroups.Count; i++)
    {
        int index = i;
        UnityAction<bool> fn;
        onOffInfoPointsGroups[index].onValueChanged.AddListener(fn = func => OnOffInfoPointsGroup(index));
        removers.Add(fn);
    }

    return () => removers.ForEach(f => f());
}
```

When you call AddToggleEvents(), you'd call it like this:

```
RemoveToggleEvents = AddToggleEvents();
```

And of course, you'll need to stash the unsubscriber action somewhere:

```
UnityAction RemoveToggleEvents; // TODO: Decide on a scope for this variable
```

And now removing all the listeners is easy.

```
RemoveToggleEvents();
```

#### Handle with care

Just take the usual care to avoid double-subscribing and overwriting your unsubscriber, avoiding null references, not creating closures on loop variables, etc.