# Check for text change event in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using TextMeshPro with an input field. I am searching for a input character and replace it with another character. I can do it easily with Update() function but the calls are quite expensive. How do I create an event to check if a text field has been changed?

EDIT: Based on the user's answer, I did try to use onValueChanged, but I received an exception error - `StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow.`

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class TextChangeEvent : MonoBehaviour {
   
   public TMP_InputField textInput_;   
   
   public void Start(){
     textInput_.onValueChanged.AddListener (delegate { myTextChanged(); });
   }

   public void myTextChanged(){
     textInput_.text = textInput_.text.Replace("World", "Unity");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what you are doing in

```
textInput_.text = textInput_.text.Replace("World", "Unity");
```

is changing the text

→ soooo again the event `onValueChanged` is called

→ again `myTextChanged` is called

→ it again changes the text

→ soooo again the event `onValueChanged` is called

→ .......... ENDLESS LOOP

What you can try to do is

```
public TMP_InputField textInput_;   
   
public void Start()
{
    // onValueChanged expects a `void(string)` so instead of adding an anonymous 
    // delegate you can never remove again rather make sure your method implements 
    // the correct signature and add it directly
    textInput_.onValueChanged.AddListener(myTextChanged);
}

// We need this signature in order to directly add and remove this method as 
// a listener for the onValueChanged event
public void myTextChanged(string newText)
{
    // temporarily remove your callback
    textInput_.onValueChanged.RemoveListener(myTextChanged);

    // change the text without being notified about it
    textInput_.text = newText.Replace("World", "Unity");

    // again attach the callback
    textInput_.onValueChanged.AddListener(myTextChanged);
}
```

---

In newer versions there is also directly

```
textInput_.SetTextWithoutNotify(newText.Replace("World", "Unity"));
```

which basically does what the name says: It sets the text value but doesn't invoke the `onValueChanged` event.

Comment: Perfect. Works like I want. Thanks :)

Comment: I just have one issue, I am getting an error that says ```cannot convert from 'method group' to 'UnityAction<string>'```

Comment: @Max no as said do not use `delegate` .. rather make sure that your `myTextChanged` method takes a `string` as parameter ... just copied my code as it is into a new empty `MonoBehaviour` script and get no errors ;)

Comment: Ah okay thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this from Unity Documentation: [OnValueChanged](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onValueChanged.html)

Edit 1:

 I researched a problem and i did read this post: [Remove listener with one parameter in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63470790/remove-listener-with-one-parameter-in-unity)

 The problem is that you are changing the value when u detect a change, but this change you have done triggers in recurrency to infinity... So the solution is to remove the listener when you are changing value and then you need to add the listener again.

Comment: I did try it, it caused ```StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow.```. I will update my question.

Comment: Updated answer.